# Was my question good?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've had some pretty [hit](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7039/does-milk-in-black-tea-completely-abolish-all-positive-effects-of-the-tea)-[and](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/can-eating-hot-peppers-while-pregnant-affect-the-fetus-skin)-[miss](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/can-someone-keep-a-razor-blade-in-his-mouth-without-injury) questions, and have been doubting myself when it comes time to post a new question.  I know some SE sites, if not all, require that some research be done before asking, yet there are many questions without much research effort where a simple Google search can give good answers, yet the question still gets lots of views and votes.

Specifically for this site, we need to have a hard claim and proof of said claim, correct?

My latest question is: [Does sleeping on your left side, while pregnant, improve blood flow](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9763/does-sleeping-on-your-left-side-while-pregnant-improve-blood-flow)?

I just posted where I heard the claim and gave a link to it (babycenter.com), and asked a straightforward yes or no question.  I've seen and heard this claim a lot while doing baby/pregnancy searches, but I'm skeptical and would like hard proof.  I have not dug any deeper into finding out myself, which might be seen as a lack of research effort, but If I do dig deeper, I'd end up getting the answer myself, and this site wouldn't benefit from the Q&A.

So my question is, was this a good question for this site?  Should I do more research?  If members are required to do more research before posting, couldn't that possibly decrease the amount people use this site?

Also, aside from linking to the FAQ, do you have any suggestions/tips on asking/answering questions (like where do you go before posting a question, what advanced Google search operators do you use when researching, etc.)?

Answer (score 6):

For the moment, I can’t think of any reason against the question. I think it’s a justified question, it fits the site, and it’s reasonably researched.

Unless you want to answer the question yourself, or the claim is truly trivial, you’re not required to research the answer yourself. What you *need* to do is research a notable claim, and make it apparent in the question.

You’ve done that. Full steam ahead.

In particular, you link to a notable claim which itself fails to cite any sources which could be used to answer this question trivially, and the claim is strong enough to be skeptical of.

Regarding your other questions, the tea-related question *would* actually be fine, weren’t it for the fact that nobody is qualified enough to answer it since the answer simply isn’t well established yet.

The peppers/baby question doesn’t really have a notable reference for the claim but even so I think it’s actually fine.

Only the razor blade question isn’t that great, for the reasons outlined in the comments.

Comment: The question seems fine to me. I was answering but you preceded me by seconds!

Comment: Thank you, Konrad & Skilvvz!